# Can anyone recommend a pre-commit web based diff viewer for subversion?

Tags: svn, diff, pre-commit

*Edited to make my requirements a little more clear*

I would love to find a decent web viewer similar to Trac's changeset page: http://trac.edgewall.org/changeset/10173. The only catch is that I need it to be pre-commit. These are for small changes that don't justify a branch/merge. Anyone know of such a tool?

Must have:

- Must be pre-commit
- Must have a
  solution for each platform: Linux,
  Mac and Windows

Nice to have:

- Run it hot. What I mean by that is to
  have the ability to run it locally
  showing the modifications in my
  current working dir. To be able to
  `svn st | diffwebclient` would be +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Atlassian's FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) togetger with [Crucible has a feature](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/tour/pre-post-commit.jsp) allowing you to view a diff. Also it lets you do a code review at the same time.

Comment: I think this will be the winner here at work since we just migrated to Jira. Thx.

Comment: You are welcome. Previously we've been using Trac but FishEye is a bit more usable. And I like the integration between Jira and FishEye.

Answer (score 3):

How about rietveld. Have you checked that out?

- http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/rietveld.html

There is a public instance of rietveld running at

- http://codereview.appspot.com/

[Edit: Another promising web based diff viewer]

- http://developer.spikesource.com/wiki/index.php/Projects:JSBlend

Comment: I'm definitely going to check this out. Ty.

Comment: @Chris: I have added another one that looks good and doesn't seem heavy weight.

Answer (score 1):

According to the FAQ on reviewboard they are going after pre-commit after 1.0 release. http://www.reviewboard.org

Answer (score 0):

[Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/docs/manual/VersionControl.html)

Comment: I love winmerge but I don't see any web viewer there.